# Logistic Model involving a population already at max capacity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**QUESTION:**

Suppose $P(t)$ is the mass of a pollutant in kilograms in a lake at time $t$ in weeks.
Further suppose that fresh water flows into the lake at $5 × 10^8$ L per week and the
same amount of lake water flows out. Assume that the volume of the lake is $5 ×10^{10}$ L
and the initial concentration of the pollutant is $0.01$ kilograms per litre. Find an
expression for $P(t)$.

**Solution:**

Given that the pollutant's initial concentration is $0.01$kg/L, the initial amount of pollutant is $0.01 \times 5\times10^{10} = 5\times10^8$. Since only fresh water flows in, the pollutant is at its maximum capacity. Therefore, we get the logistic equation:

$P(t) = \frac{5\times10^{8}}{1+Ae^{-kt}}$
Where $A=\frac{P_{max} - P_{initial}}{P_{initial}}=\frac{5\times10^{8} - 5\times10^{8}}{5\times10^8} = 0$

Then

$P(t)=\frac{5\times10^8}{1+(0)(e^{-kt})} = 5\times10^8$

This matches the idea that if $P$ is at maximum capacity, then $\frac{dP}{dt} = 0$

Is this a correct solution? If not, could I get any hints as to what I've done wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: The solution should be exponential decay, not the logistic equation. There is no maximum capacity, $P'(t)=-0.01P(t)$ is the differential equation.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thank you for your help.

What I got as a result is $P(t) = (5\times10^8)(e^{-0.01t})$. Did I do this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.